# insert a new document from querying combined collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Nosql world and meteor, I have two collections, taskCollectioin and workersCollection and my goal is to match each task to the available timeslot in workersCollection. my tasks collection has fields {client,task-name,time-flag,assigned=false} and my workers collection has field {name, timeslot:[slot, available]}. I have created also result collection called matchCollection result that need to insert a document resulting in matching of each task to available worker.

My question: Since we are dealing with  querying from two different collection and comparing their field for matching, how would you implement a function in meteor that solves following psuedo code algorithm?

```
'FOR each task FROM TaskCollection
   | IF (assigned == false)
   |  |  get the task flag(for example: 10-12 pm)     
   | ENDIF   
   |  FOR each worker From collection
   |  |  **get worker slots
   |  |    IF (worker timeslot is availible for a given task time-flag)
   |  |    |   1-assign the task to the worker
   |  |    |   2-set the task assigned to true
   |  |    |   3-set the timeslot.available to false
   |  |    |   4-create a document in MatchCollection
   |  |    END IF 
   |  ENDFOR     
   ENDFOR'
```

Comment: Hey, you can do that with aggregation, have you already read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will achieve this using aggregation... [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)
You have to study this part.

Comment: Aggregation you can create or add documents to collections.